# Django CreateView - How to show a related field (FK) like integer instead of select?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-generic-views

Hi (sorry for my bad english), i'm trying to show a form using a number input instead a select in a FK Relation on django model, but i cant make it.

The thing is that i need to fill the ID of the product manually writing the id in a input box, but django automatically makes the select form with all the products!

this is what i have in forms.py

```
class PurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = [
            'date',
            'supplier',
            'warehouse',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={
                    'type': 'date',
                }),
        }


class PurchaseItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseItem
        fields = [
            'product',
            'quantity',
            'net_purchase_price',
            'sell_price',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'product': forms.NumberInput(),
        }


PurchaseFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Purchase,
        PurchaseItem,
        fields='__all__',
        extra = 10,
    )
```

this is my view

```
class PruchaseCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'purchases/create_purchase.html'
    form_class = PurchaseForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PruchaseCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = PurchaseFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = PurchaseFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return redirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())  
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

i try with the widget NumberInput but nothing!!! any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the custom form when you call `inlineformset_factory`:

```
PurchaseFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Purchase,
    PurchaseItem,
    form=PurchaseItemForm
    fields='__all__',
    extra = 10,
)
```